# Difference between FloatingPointRoundingRule.down and FloatingPointRoundingRule.towardsZero in Foundation

Tags: swift, foundation

`FloatingPointRoundingRule.down` and `FloatingPointRoundingRule.towardsZero` both are rounded towards zero(rounded to nearest Int value). Then what is difference between them and at which scenario what type should be used?

Comment: "both are rounded towards zero" No. Did you forget about negative numbers?

Comment: "rounded to nearest Int value", this isn't completely correct either depending on the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case `towardZero` acts opposite for positive and negative numbers.

Here is an image for better understanding:

[image: Demo]

And based on the documentation:

###### [case down](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpointroundingrule/down)

> Round to the closest allowed value that is less than or equal to the source.

```
(5.2).rounded(.down) // 5.0
(5.5).rounded(.down) // 5.0
(-5.2).rounded(.down) // -6.0
(-5.5).rounded(.down) // -6.0
```

###### [case towardZero](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpointroundingrule/towardzero)

> Round to the closest allowed value whose magnitude is less than or equal to that of the source.

```
(5.2).rounded(.towardZero) // 5.0
(5.5).rounded(.towardZero) // 5.0
(-5.2).rounded(.towardZero) // -5.0
(-5.5).rounded(.towardZero) // -5.0
```